# Lock computer and Log user name application

Tags: windows-7, logging

I have a windows7 computer which is connected to a mechanical system. This computer has 2 user accounts one admin and one for the factory users. What I want to do is to have some kind of lock/log application where when the user logs in to the machine with the generic user account they will have to enter their name then "sign in" once they do that their sign-in time will be logged until the machine is locked then sign-out will be logged as well. I wonder if any idea there is a program that can do this or a way that I can do it?

Comment: How many different users?

Comment: @Moab around 200, but it increases and decreases since the factory users are not fixed.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it natively in windows, so you would have to use a third party utility, which is off topic here at SU. Maybe someone will have a solution later today, interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Every user could have their own acc (This can be scripted) and Windows, by default, logs all login and logout events (Event ID 4624 and 4634, respectively). If users using that PC are changed in high frequency, You could make a 200 Generic name accs and keep the record of Acc <-> "Current worker" relationship.
2. You could add a LOGON policy - every time "Factory users acc" sign in some task get called:

   - Script made in .VBS, .BAT(CMD), PowerShell
   - App made with C/C++, C#, any other language
   - If computer has internet access You could use Microsoft/Google forms and call them at logon
3. Maybe there is a third party solution

Comment: This is what I initially thought as well. The downside of this solution is if the factory users forget to logout.

Comment: @Burgi There si a [Group Policy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c83443b-05f4-405c-8587-ee510063c83f/logoff-idle-users?forum=winserverGP) and [Task Scheduler](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d358382c-e91b-4e91-a1e8-04c53cfd91ce/automatic-logout-after-inactivityidle?forum=w7itprogeneral) solution for that.